# Data-dump analysis idea : Detecting the Jon Skeet effect

Tags: discussion, data-analysis

I think it would be interesting to see if there is a Jon Skeet effect on question closure.

I've recently seen two heavily downvoted questions (one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20123/jon-skeet-should-be-ashamed)) which AREN'T closed, and I suspect that it's because they have an answer by Jon.

I also wonder whether there aren't people 'following' Jon around, and questions that he answers automatically get more views.

Would be also interesting to see if this is a Jon Skeet effect, or if it is a high rep user effect.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure there are a few people who follow me around to some extent. Eric Lippert seems to comment on my answers more than would seem likely if he were just reading a random sample of C# questions - although that's an effect for which I'm profoundly grateful, as his comments are always insightful.

I believe the linked Meta question already had plenty of downvotes before I answered though - and it's worth remembering that downvotes on a question on meta don't really equate to downvotes on a Stack Overflow question. They're expressions of disagreement rather than suggestions that the question is asked badly etc. Examples in Stack Overflow would be more interesting.

I wouldn't be surprised if there were an effect, but one that's a little more subtle - it's possible that if I answer a question, some people *may* not downvote it when they otherwise would. That doesn't necessarily have to be due to me being me, however. You might think a question is generally useless until you see an answer which interprets the question slightly differently, for example.

Comment: Yes, there is worse than being stalked by Eric Lippert :)

Comment: ... and if I'm right, you've just guaranteed a long life for my question, so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be to hard to pull off. Just two subsets of the data. One with Skeet and one without. Plot a graph and ???. Profit!

Comment: I also think there is an Ólafur Waage effect. Questions/Answers by me on meta have a high chance of getting volcano/viking related comments.

Comment: Especially if you do it yourself. ;)