# Is there a way to find out how many of my votes went to Jon Skeet?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, data-analysis

Can I find out how many of my 1000 votes went to Jon? Having been an active user for 1½ years, I am interested to learn whether after such a long time I actually favor him (or anyone else) by a significant margin, or whether my votes are surprisingly evenly distributed.

I have searched Meta, but the closest I could get was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27524/data-dump-analysis-idea-detecting-the-jon-skeet-effect) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005), which is to say: not close at all.

Some might object that there could be security issues with mining for that information. However, if I simply visited every single question Jon has ever asked or answered (roughly 10,000, holy cow of Moscow!), I *could* count the votes I have given to him. If I then repeated the same process for every user (roughly 330,000), I *could* draw the kind of graph I am envisioning. (Yes, I could optimize that process somewhat by "simply" visiting all questions.)

So, I am not asking for access to data that is not available to me anyway. I am only asking if there's a way to get the data which I do have access to in a more convenient format.

Comment: Jon Skeet pwns all votes.

Comment: Step 1: Perl. Step 2: ??? Step 3: Profit!

Comment: Well, it sounds like you already know your total number of votes.  If you simply subtract the number of votes that Jon Skeet permitted you to cast for other users, the difference will be your answer.

Comment: @mmyers: well, I figured as much, and I *am* right in the middle of step 2 right now. Anyway, you probably don't want my script to be playing fugues on your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should typically email us directly if you want your own personal voting information disclosed.

Our email address is at the bottom of every page we serve..

Comment: Jeff, interesting information! I consider not only voting, but whole my profile to be personal information, giving others a clue how do I spend my time... I would like to hide my profile say from users with rep < 200. Would that be ever possible?

Answer (score 4):

Vote data is anonymous in the dump/api and there's no way to find out who you up voted on the site. The only thing you could do is visit all of Jon Skeet's answers and look for that orange tick. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks for keeping your fingers crossed, Andy E's head. I'll be off then!

Comment: You can always ask a question on SO on how to automate that process…

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with downvotes, but not upvotes.

This is because non community-wiki downvotes (costing you 1 reputation) are tracked in your [Reputation Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation). However, upvotes (costing you 0 reputation) are not. So there is no way to even find out what you voted on without going to all the questions and just looking.

In the interest of completeness

Using the [Reputation Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and a fairly simple console app (or even some text editor magic) you can find all of your downvotes. You only need to filter by the number three (**3**) in the first column. The next column is the post ID.

So now you have the post ID of every post you've ever downvoted.

Using the [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) you can determine the author of each of those posts. Either individually (pain) or through some SQL magic you could aggregate and figure out who you downvoted the most.

Although, to be honest, it's not a very interesting thing to do in your case. What with you having only 10 downvotes on StackOverflow.

Comment: Just a quick note - community wiki down votes don't appear in the rep audit (since there's no rep change).

Comment: And you're suggesting someone downvoted Jon Skeet :)